# How to set up directory level triggers in AWS S3 for Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a directory structure as shown below

```
S3 Bucket
 -logs/
  -product1_log.txt
  -product2_log.txt
 -images/
 -products/
```

There are a couple of directories mentioned above in the S3 bucket, now whenever a new file gets added to the logs folder, I have a lambda function that updates the timestamp in my MongoDB.

### Requirement

- Trigger lambda function only when `logs` folder gets updated, update to other folders should not trigger the lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact same use case described in the below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-filtering.html